# What does it mean to find a general formula of a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, exponentiation

> Given matrix $$A = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 4  \\-2 & -4\end{bmatrix}$$ find the general formula of $A^n$. Hint: diagonalize matrix $A$.

---

What does it mean to find a general formula of $A^n$? I don't understand the exercise itself. I have a guess, that seems logically correct:

$A^2=\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 4  \\
-2 & -4  \\
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 4  \\
-2 & -4  \\
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
-4 & -8  \\
4 & 8  \\
\end{bmatrix}=(-2)^1A$

$A^3=\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 4  \\
-2 & -4  \\
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 4  \\
-2 & -4  \\
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 4  \\
-2 & -4  \\
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
-8 & -16  \\
8 & 16  \\
\end{bmatrix}=(-2)^2A$

Therefore:
$A^n=(-2)^{n-1}A$

But I'm not sure whether is what's needed, and I didn't had to diagonalize the matrix using this method.

Comment: You start with a *general* 2 by 2 matrix, and then when you go for a guess you start with a *particular* 2 by 2 matrix. That won't give you the general power.

Comment: Oh, that's the original matrix. I'll edit it

Comment: Rus-- in that case your general guess looks right. Could try to prove by induction.

Comment: I just wasn't sure about what the exercise wanted from me. And the 'diagonalize the matrix' part confused me a lot

Comment: Looks like your $A^3$ evaluation is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me explain the "diagonalize" part:

If we could write $A = PDP^{-1}$ for a diagonal matrix $D$, then it would follow that $A^n = PD^n P^{-1}$. The advantage is that $D^n$ is simple to calculate: if $D = \text{diag}(a_1, \cdots, a_k)$, then $D^n = \text{diag}(a_1^n, \cdots, a^n_k)$.